# How to find ',' in a string in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL, just wanted to know that how can we search for "," in a string and want the particular string before and after.
Example : tampa,florida

It has to search for , if in that string if there is , it should return tampa   and florida  we can use string replace but it will not work in my condition because i need to map, tampa and florida to different set of variables dont even know how the inbound would look like to use string range.
                                                                     .

Thanks,
Arya

Answer (score 4):

Unless there is some further condition, you could do it this way:

```
split tampa,florida ,
```

This command gives as result a list containing the two strings "tampa" and "florida".

Documentation: [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The shortest piece of code to do this would be using regular expressions:

```
if {[regexp {(.+),(.+)} $string a b c]} {
   # $a is the complete match. But we don't care
   # about that so we ignore it

   puts $b; #tampa
   puts $c; #florida
}
```

The regular expression `(.+),(.+)` means:

```
(
  .  any character
  +  one or more of the above
)    save it in a capture group
,    comma character
(
  .  any character
  +  one or more of the above
)    save it in a capture group
```

See the documentation of regular expression syntax in tcl for more about regular expressions: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm

---

But if you're not familiar with regular expressions and want an alternative way of doing this you can use the various [string](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm) commands. This is one way to do it:

```
set comma_location [string first "," $string]
if {$comma_location > -1} {
    set a [string range $string 0 [expr {$comma_location -1}]
    set b [string range $string [expr {$comma_location +1}] end]
    puts $a; #tampa
    puts $b; #florida
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant of slebetman's last answer.

```
proc before_after {value find {start 0}} {
    set index [string first $find $value $start]
    set left_side [string range $value $start [expr $index - 1]]
    set right_side [string range $value [expr $index + 1] end]
    return [list $left_side $right_side]
}

puts [before_after "tampa,fl" ","]
```

output:

```
tampa fl
```